# Matrix calculus : Derivative with respect to two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, hessian-matrix

I have a function of two variables, $\vec{x_i} \in \mathbb{R}^n $ and $\vec{y_j} \in \mathbb{R}^n$:

$f(\vec{x_i},\vec{y_j}) =\sum_\limits{i,j} \left( \vec{x_i} \cdot \vec{y_j} + z_{ij} \right)^2$

I am trying to find the second derivative of this expression. I understand how to accomplish the task when keeping the $\vec{x}_i$ or $\vec{y}_j$ constant but I cannot figure out a way to do it when both of the variables are not constant. I would really appreciate being pointed to a certain direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(e_k)$ be the standard basis vectors and $(X,Y)$ be the matrices whose columns are the $(x_i,\,y_j)$ vectors, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
 x_i &= Xe_i, &y_j = Ye_j \cr
 x_i\cdot y_j &= e_i^TX^TY&e_j = X^TY:e_ie_j^T \cr 
}$$ where colon represents the trace/Frobenius product, i.e. $\,\,A:B={\rm Tr}(A^TB)$

Define $K=\begin{bmatrix}0&I\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and concatenate the XY-matrices into a single matrix $\,\,W^T=[X^T\,\,Y^T]$

Note that $X^TY=W^TKW$.

Using these new variables, rewrite the cost function and find its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 f &= (X^TY+Z):(X^TY+Z)   \cr
   &= (W^TKW+Z):(W^TKW+Z) \cr
df &= 2(W^TKW+Z):d(W^TKW) \cr
   &= 2(W^TKW+Z):(dW^TKW+W^TK\,dW) \cr
   &= 2\Big(KW(W^TKW+Z)^T+K^TW(W^TKW+Z)\Big):dW \cr
G=\frac{\partial f}{\partial W}
 &= 2KW\big(W^TKW+Z\big)^T+2K^TW\big(W^TKW+Z\big) \cr
}$$
Now find the differential of the gradient 
$$\eqalign{
dG
 &= 2KdW\big(W^TKW+Z\big)^T+2K^TdW\big(W^TKW+Z\big) \cr
 &+\,2KW\big(dW^TKW\big)^T+2K^TW\big(dW^TKW\big) \cr
 &+\,2KW\big(W^TKdW\big)^T+2K^TW\big(W^TKdW\big) \cr
\cr
}$$
Shuffling these terms around to produce the hessian is a tedious exercise, which I'll leave to you.

Keep in mind that, since the gradient is a matrix, the resulting hessian will be a 4th order tensor. 
$${\mathcal H} = \frac{\partial G}{\partial W} = \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial W\partial W}$$
One way to handle the term-shuffling is to flatten the expressions using **vectorization**, i.e. 
$$A\,dX\,B = (B^T\otimes A)\,{\rm vec}(dX)$$ 
where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product.

You'll also need a special permutation matrix $P\,$ called the [Commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) to reduce some of the intermediate terms.
$${\rm vec}(dX^T)=P\,{\rm vec}(dX)$$